# Proof of complex conjugate symmetry property of DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-algebra, proof

According to the Proof :

> \begin{align}
> X_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_ke^{-j\frac{2\pi k n}{N}}\\
> X_{N-n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_ke^{-j\frac{2\pi k (N-n)}{N}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_k e^{-j 2\pi k}e^{j\frac{2\pi k n}{N}}
> \end{align}
>
> Using $\exp(-j2\pi k) = 1 \quad \forall \ k$
>
> \begin{align}
> X_{N-n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_k e^{j\frac{2\pi k n}{N}}\\
> \end{align}

How is $\exp(-j2\pi k) = 1 \quad \forall \ k$ true ? Doesn't it mean $-j2\pi k = 0$ ? But that's not possible right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

According to [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) we have
$$e^{-j2\pi k}=\cos(2\pi k)-j\sin(2\pi k)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 6):

**Did you ever wonder about where $\pi $ came from?** Watch out...

Let us first draw this weird function complex exponential $e^{-2j\pi t}$ for several discrete values of  $t\in[0,10]$ (the little blue  circles joined by line segments):

[image: complex Fourier phasor]

On one axis, the variable $t$, on the others the real and imaginary parts, respectively. It looks like an infinite spring. Now draw the function at integer values  $k\in [0,10] \cap \mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,\ldots,10\}$. These are the tiny red crosses, joined by red segments. They exactly have a real part equal to one, and an imaginary part equal to zero, because  $e^{-2j\pi k} = 1+0j$.

It might seem weird with respect to the standard   behavior, expected from the exponential, but the complex argument $-2j\pi k$ is a deal changer. For real $t$, $e^{ t} = 1$ has only one solution. But  $e^{-2j\pi t} = 1$ has an infinity of solutions. Its maps the real axis onto the unit circle, in a periodic way.

In fact, in some math books, like Walter Rudin's [Real and Complex analysis](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Real_and_complex_analysis.html?id=Z_fuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (very first pages), $e$ comes first, and $\pi$ subsequently. One first defines, for any complex $z$:

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

which is an absolutely convergent series. And then you get some results, like $e^z$ is never equal to zero. But the most striking one is:

> There exists a positive number $\pi$ such that $e^{\pi j/2} = j$ and such that $e^z = 1$ if and only if $z/(2\pi j )$ is an integer.

So $\pi $ can be defined as the "measure" of the periodicity of the everlasting spring of the complex exponential. The site [Euler's Equation](http://www.songho.ca/math/euler/euler.html) provides other nice graphs.

Comment: That's cool stuff there!

Answer (score 5):

Remember that $e^z$ has a very different meaning than $e^x$ (taking $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

If the exponent was real, then, as you state in your question:

$$e^x = 1 \iff x=0$$

However, when the exponent is complex, this function acquires a very different meaning. Let $z=x+jy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j$ is the imaginary unit. Then

$$e^z=e^{x+jy}=e^x \cdot e^{jy}$$

The first factor is real and, therefore, equals $1$ if and only if $x=0$. The second factor, however, has a purely imaginary exponent (such as the one in your question). Such a function [can be calculated as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula):

$$e^{jy}=\cos(y)+j\sin(y)$$

As you can see, this function is periodic. In your case, $y=-2\pi k$, with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$e^{-j2\pi k}=\cos(-2\pi k)+j\sin(-2\pi k)$$

Cosine is an even function and sine is odd, so

$$\cos(-2\pi k)+j\sin(-2\pi k)=\cos(2\pi k)-j\sin(2\pi k)$$

What are the values of $\cos(2\pi k)$ and $\sin(2\pi k)$? Well... they seem to depend on $k$. But... do they? The answer is **no**.

The cosine equals $1$ for any multiple of $2\pi$. The sine equals $0$ for any multiple of $2\pi$. This leads to the final result:

$$e^{-j2\pi k}=\cos(2\pi k)-j\sin(2\pi k)=1-j0=1 \ \forall k$$