# $e^{j\omega}$ on unit circle

Tags: discrete-signals, magnitude

I am new to DSP, and I'm self studying. I am confused about the magnitude of $e^{j\omega}$ - where $\omega$ is the normalized angular frequency - when we are on the unit circle.

According to the text book, it's $|e^{j\omega}|=1$. But why is that? I'd really appreciate it is someone could please kindly explain this to me.

Comment: My first blog article titled "The Exponential Nature of the Complex Unit Circle" starts with the definition of $i$ (aka $j$) and uses simple algebra to work up to an understanding of Euler's equation which is the answer you are looking for.  You can find my article here: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning: $|e^{j\omega}|$ is equal to $1$ if and only if $\omega$ is a real number. More generally, for $z$ complex,  $|e^{z}|=e^{\Re{z}}$.

This really depends in your prior knowledge, because functions like exponentials, sines or cosines, can be developed in different ways. Here, I'll assume you know about sines  and cosines, as you refer to **angular** frequency. Then, an historical way to define the exponential is via [Euler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), for instance:

$$e^{j\omega} = \cos \omega+j\sin \omega\,.$$

Then, through [Argand's complex plane interpretation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html), you can interpret a complex number as a point with  2D coordinates $(x,y) \leftrightarrow  x+jy$: the real part refers to the $X$-axis, the imaginary one to the $Y$-axis. Thus, obviously, $e^{j\omega}$ has the coordinates of a point on the $(0,0)$-center circle with radius $1$, hence the magnitude  $|e^{j\omega}|$ is equal to the radius, or  $(\cos \omega)^2+(\sin \omega)^2=1^2$.

In more modern versions, $e^z$ is defined by a series (see [Proof of complex conjugate symmetry property of DFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37792/15892)), and $\cos$ and $\sin$ are derived for it, so they don't come first.

Comment: “In more modern versions”, I like that!

Answer (score 4):

By [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), assuming $\omega$ is a real number:
$$
e^{j \omega} = \cos(\omega) + j \sin(\omega)
$$

The definition of magnitude for a complex number $z = x + jy$ is:
$$
|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2},
$$
therefore:
$$
\left|e^{j \omega} \right| = \sqrt{\cos^2\omega + \sin^2\omega} = 1
$$
by [trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities).

Comment: So it's always true, right? Doesn't matter if we are moving on the unit circle or not.

Comment: @Shady correct. The second link shows why

Comment: Always, as long as $\omega$ is a real number

Comment: @LaurentDuval eventhough you are spot on your warning on the type of variable being used in the exponential, as you can remember at the very beginning of Diff.Eq., Signals&Systems, etc. the quantitty was **first** introduced as the general *complex exponential* : $e^s$ with $s = \sigma + j \omega$ with real $\sigma,\omega$ and then $e^{s} = e^{\sigma + j\omega}$ was the natural consequent, upon which the interpretation of $e^{j \omega}$ needed no more **re-definition** for $\omega$ to be real. hence I think **un-defining** $\omega$ as complex would be against the *Occam's Razor* principle. ;-)

Comment: even though it was not explicitly given as an axiom, i had always considered $\Im\{\omega\}=0$ as an implicit axiom.

Comment: @Fat32 Complex eigenvalues remain at the core of any fully-real LTI systems. So, I kinda believe that complex numbers are fundamentally more central than real ones, which are mere shadows of the formers.

Comment: @robert-bristow-johnson Mathematically, yes, of course. In discrete practice, some meets floats sometimes, and the imaginary part is not always really zero, and this should be taken care of

Comment: @LaurentDuval, i still don't understand where the presumption that $\omega$ might not be real in $e^{j\omega}$ comes from.

Comment: // *"complex numbers are fundamentally more central than real..."* // i think that complex numbers are **mathematically** more **general** than real numbers, but i don't really perceive reality in terms of complex numbers.  all of the physical quantities that i perceive are real.

Comment: I was worried that somebody might think that $e^{ia}$ as always unit modulus, without checking that this $a$ is real

Comment: I understand the need to be complete, but I think it's clear from context that $\omega$ is angular frequency (real quantity). If it was $\sigma$, or some other variable, I would agree that more explanation would be needed. I'll go ahead and edit my answer to put this to bed

Comment: @LaurentDuval you are a successful genius at **shadowing** your fllaws behind your  brilliant (yet irrelevant) explanations.. ;-))

Comment: I just call this unconscious intuition :)

Answer (score 1):

$Ke^{j\theta}$ is a mathematical way of describing a phasor with magnitude K and angle $\theta$. I think knowing this simple relationship takes a lot of the mystery away; which is proven by Euler's identity as Carlos has shown.

What is interesting is if you raise ANY real number to the power of j the magnitude will be 1!

You can see this by solving for the magnitude of a complex number which is the square root of the complex conjugate multiplication:

$\sqrt{x^j x^{-j}} = \sqrt{x^0}  = 1$